# All Menu Items Disappear Seemingly at Random

Tags: menus

For the last month or so, seemingly at random and with no discernible pattern, my menu disappears. However, when I look at the Dashboard, what I find is that all the menu items have been deleted but the menu itself is still there. I can select and add the items back and they reappear. There is nothing in my error logs, and I'd guess it's happening about once/week, though that's just a guess.

I am using a modified default theme, though the theme has not changed for over a year and this problem started recently.

Because I cannot predict when this will happen it's difficult for me to remove all plugins indefinitely while I wait as it will break lots of functionality on my site. However, none of the plugins are directly related to the menu system. And they've all been in place for quite a while.

I've seen some posts that seem related to this problem but they all involve huge menus. My menu only has 4 items! The items all point to Pages. The structure/contents of the menu have not changed for a couple years.

Any ideas? Even ideas on how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

Comment: I would go out and say it is nearly impossible to pin point an intermitted fault, as it comes and goes for no aparent reason. What makes is more tougher is when debug is "on", and you get no error when your menu fails. It is irrelevant to disable all plugins one by one and swithing to a bundled theme, as you never know when your menu will fail again

Comment: To me, programmatically speaking, it seems you have a plugin that deletes terms of the taxonomy "nav_menu" every X days.

Comment: Not the first time I see something like this reported ([Nav menu items disappearing (but not immediately)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64487/nav-menu-items-disappearing-but-not-immediately)), had never seen solved though. :(

Comment: I'd start using a log file - the only chance to catch randomly appearing errors. Better use both, a PHP and the WP log file.

Comment: I would bet on database failure or database corruption but that is just guessing. As already mentioned, watch the log files and try to get more information.

Comment: i'll try the troubleshooting suggestions and report back

Comment: We are experiencing a similar bug which has to do with the `wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete` cron job, I have asked an own question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145953/wp-delete-auto-drafts-deletes-links-in-menus.

Comment: Other Q was traced down to the plugin messing up `WP_Query` in [`wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items/). Might be similar issue with anything filtering `WP_Query` and not doing it robustly enough.

Comment: I would try adding another menu and seeing if that one behaves the same way.  If so, maybe Nabil K is on to something.

Comment: I appear to have solved the problem by disabling the Stealth Publish plug-in. I got the idea from a related question:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145953/wp-delete-auto-drafts-deletes-links-in-menus . Apparently it had something to do with `wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete` getting called when there was also a draft page in place.