# wp_delete_auto_drafts() deletes links in menus

Tags: php, menus, wp-cron, draft

Since yesterday the `wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete` cron job somehow deletes all page entries from our menus. All entries in the table `wp_postmeta` with `meta_key = '_menu_item_object'` and `meta_value = 'page'` get deleted in the process. By tracing back the DELETE query I found out that the menu entries are deleted by a function called `_wp_delete_post_menu_item`. I got the following stacktrace for that function:

```
#0  _wp_delete_post_menu_item(3244)
#1  call_user_func_array(_wp_delete_post_menu_item, Array ([0] => 3244))
called at [/srv/www/htdocs/biva/wp-includes/plugin.php:470]
#2  do_action(delete_post, 3244) called at
[/srv/www/htdocs/biva/wp-includes/post.php:2483]
#3  wp_delete_post(3244, 1) called at
[/srv/www/htdocs/biva/wp-includes/post.php:5645]
#4  wp_delete_auto_drafts()
#5  call_user_func_array(wp_delete_auto_drafts, Array ()) called at
[/srv/www/htdocs/biva/wp-includes/plugin.php:546]
#6  do_action_ref_array(wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete, Array ()) called
at [/srv/www/htdocs/biva/wp-cron.php:100]
```

But I'm stuck here, I'm not a wordpress developer and I have no clue why deleting old drafts results in deleting attached menu entries although the main pages still exist.

**Workaround:**
As a workaround we added the following to the top of `wp-config`, wich will disable `wp-cron`:

```
/** Disable wp-cron to prevent menu from getting deleted. Detailed Bug description:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145953 **/
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

If you are experiencing similar difficulties you might try locking the rows in the table `wp_postmeta` with `meta_key = '_menu_item_object'` and `meta_value = 'page'` and then tracing back the error message when WP trys to delete these rows, that's how we nailed down our error.

**Reproduce the Error:**
It is definitely the stealth publish plugin that is causing our error, one can easily reproduce it, by doing the following:

1. Install a fresh Wordpress 3.9.1.
2. Install the stealth publish plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/stealth-publish.
3. Create a few test pages and add them to a new menu.
4. Create a new page, with some dummy content, **but do not save it!**. Leave the page without saving.
5. Change the system time 8 days into the future.
6. The `wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete` cron job will run because it runs daily and it hasn't run for 7 days as soon as you visit your page. It will then find your never saved dummy page delete it as it is older than 7 days and the menu will vanish.
7. You might need to refresh the page a few times till the effect becomes visible.

I've recorded a screencast on how to reproduce the error (but I took not the time to comment it): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9CTggjIfDY

Comment: This is very strange. Auto draft only exists in that brief time when you open editor to start on a new post, but hadn't saved it even once. Why would item like that have menu items associated with it? Puzzling.

Comment: I guess it only occurs when there are actually some drafts older than 7 days (we have a lot of drafts). Because the bug would not occur when running `wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete` twice in a short time frame. For debugging purpose I always reset the DB to the problematic state to reproduce the conditions. I believe that may also explain why others are experiencing this bug in larger time frames, assuming they have not that many drafts as we have.

Comment: Yes, but (1) you cannot add auto-draft to menu, (2) as soon as you save it — it's no longer auto-draft. So _logically_ these conditions cannot coincide. Question is why do they coincide in practice.

Comment: If you have DB state could you please dump and add to the question post item 3244 and all menu items with meta _menu_item_object_id=3244 ?

Comment: Here is quick snippet for a dump of all related stuff:
`$post_id = 3244;
var_dump( get_post( $post_id ) );
foreach ( wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items( $post_id ) as $id ) {
 var_dump( get_post( $id ), get_post_custom( $id ) );
}`

Comment: Ok, it seems like `wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items()` is seriously misfiring there. Do you have any code at all running that adjusts `WP_Query` behavior? Can you dump/log MySQL queries running when this function executes?

Comment: Is this still for `3244`? I don't see that ID in queries. Any idea what is `_stealth-publish` thing is? It's not WP core.

Comment: Im sorry my fault I've forgot to call wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items with the id.I'm going to correct that.

Comment: I've rerun wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items(3244) and changed the link. Stealth publish is a plugin our designer installed, I'm going to deactivate it and see if the bug still occurs.

Comment: Without stealth publish everything seems to run fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what normal query run by [`wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items/) looks like:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM   wp_posts 
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
               ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND wp_posts.post_type = 'nav_menu_item' 
       AND (( wp_posts.post_status <> 'trash' 
              AND wp_posts.post_status <> 'auto-draft' )) 
       AND (( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_menu_item_object_id' 
              AND Cast(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '3111' )) 
GROUP  BY wp_posts.id 
ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

This is what yours looks like:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM   wp_posts 
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
               ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 
              ON ( wp_posts.id = mt1.post_id 
                   AND mt1.meta_key = '_stealth-publish' ) 
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 
               ON ( wp_posts.id = mt2.post_id ) 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND wp_posts.post_type = 'nav_menu_item' 
       AND (( wp_posts.post_status <> 'trash' 
              AND wp_posts.post_status <> 'auto-draft' )) 
       AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_menu_item_object_id' 
               AND Cast(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '3244' ) 
              OR mt1.post_id IS NULL 
              OR ( mt2.meta_key = '_stealth-publish' 
                   AND Cast(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) != '1' ) ) 
GROUP  BY wp_posts.id 
ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

It would be my guess that `_stealth-publish` stuff has no business whatsoever interfering with querying for nav menu items.